# Load "PartialView" with template Url in localhost - IIS 7.5 - AngularJs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, url, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

RouteConfig :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Templates",
                url: "Templates/{action}/{template}",
                defaults: new {Controller = "Admin"}
                );
```

My state :

```
angular.module('uiRouterApp.newsCategories', [
        'uiRouterApp.newsCategories.Service',
        'uiRouterApp.pager.Service',
        'uiRouterApp.table.Service',
        'ui.router'
        ])
    .config(
        [
            '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
            function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                $stateProvider
                    .state('newsCategories', {
                        url: '/newsCategories/PageIndex=:PageIndex/PageSize=:PageSize/SortBy=:SortBy/SortMode=:SortMode',
                        templateUrl: '/Templates/NewsCategories/List',
                        controller: 'listCtrl'
                    });
            }
        ]
    );
```

AdminController :

```
 public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult NewsCategories(string template)
        {
            switch (template.ToLower())
            {
                case "list":
                    return PartialView(Url.Content("~/Views/Admin/Partials/NewsCategories/newsCategories.cshtml"));
                default:
                    throw new Exception("template not known");
            }
        }
    }
```

Folders :

[image]

Error :

```
GET http://localhost/Templates/NewsCategories/List 404 (Not Found)
```

Why not correct partial View address?

Please see this : [load file in localhost with iis7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241719/load-file-in-localhost-with-iis7-5)

Since this photo was displayed properly

Comment: http://localhost/Templates/NewsCategories/?template=list works?

Comment: http://localhost/OtherApk/Templates/NewsCategories/list. this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the url with leading slash, it will always create the url from the top level. That' is why url `http://localhost/Templates/NewsCategories/List` got constructed. If you remove the leading slash it always append to the current location. So if you had always same url in the whole app `http://localhost/OtherApk` you could use it. But if you created an url like that  when the current url was `http://localhost/OtherApk/something` it would construct url `http://localhost/OtherApk/something/Templates/NewsCategories/List` which is again wrong.

So what you can do is to store the base url somewhere in a config and always append to that url.

```
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost/OtherApk';    
var url = baseUrl + '/Templates/NewsCategories/List';
```

Comment: Hello @David. What of in the case of loading partial view in angular modal `templateurl`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the template URL is resolving to the Root domain, it happens because of the leading "/". On the production server that would be fine, but while debuging it can be a pain.

Try removing the leading "/":

```
templateUrl: 'Templates/NewsCategories/List'
```

Or building the full URL on the template:

```
templateUrl: 'http://localhost/OtherApk/Templates/NewsCategories/List'
```

If only the second one works, you can use a variable to hold the baseURL and change it when you are in the production server.